# I have to give Grant and With-Grant permission to a user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I am trying to set me as a grantor in SQL Server 2012.

I am logging into the database engine from my Windows account, then trying to give connect SQL  (COSQ) permission to the other account, but after applying the settings, when I opened the properties of the other user (under securables), I see the grantor is sa instead of my own Windows account:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/STG9G.png

Answer (score 0):

`GRANT… WITH GRANT` says that the person to whom you granted the permission can also grant that permission to others. I think what you're looking for is `GRANT… AS [«database principal»];`. You should only have to do this if you want the grantor to be anyone but yourself.

To further complicate things, I would bet that you're in the db_owner group. If that's the case, what I think you're seeing is that the grantee is defaulting to the owner of the database (in this case, sa).

If I may ask, why do you want the grantee to *not* be sa?

Comment: I got the solution. 
The crux is here. We have to grant the 'control server' permission to the user from 'sa' user. Then execute the following query on materDB

Execute as user = 'domain\code'
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [domain\ksingh]